# How to get MAC Address from my windows pocket PC 5.0

Tags: c#

I need to store my Pocket PC device MAC Address in my Oracle DB, In VS2008 am using .net framework is 3.5 and runtime framework is 2.0.5

Comment: You can do manually.  From cmd.exe first use >Ping IP (or device name)  Then look at ARP table >ARP -A

Answer (score 0):

I tried many types finally i got with OpennetCf dll, i helps to get connected device mac address